# Assigning current user for multiple objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my code below I want to assign  the current user to the products that are created.

**ProductsController.rb**

```
def new
  @products = Array.new(2) { Product.new }   
end

def create_multiple
  params[:product][:user_id] = current_user.id
  Product.transaction do
    begin
      @products = Product.create!(params[:products].map {|_k, up| up.merge params[:product]})
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "Success!"
    rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "An error occured, please try again."
    end
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_products_path, :method => :post do %>

  <%= date_select("product", "purchase_date")  %>

  <% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
     <%= fields_for "products[#{index}]", product do |up| %>
        <%= render "fields", :f => up %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag "Done" %>
<% end %>
```

The USER ID (current user) isn't being assigned. Any ideas on how to assign it?

Comment: @Jordan Its for my form. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I thought this was in your model, not your controller. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate a lot of logic here by remembering two facts: `create` will take an array of Hashes to create multiple objects, and its bang-method counterpart `create!` will throw an exception if any validations failed.

```
def create_multiple
  # like clyfe said, do this in a transaction
  Product.transaction do
    begin
      @products = current_user.products.create!(
        # Hash#map returns an Array, so no need to use Hash#values
        params[:products].map { |_k, up| up.merge params[:product] }
      )

      # if create! is successful...
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "Success!"

    # if it's not successful it'll throw this exception, which we can rescue
    rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "An error occured, please try again."
    end
  end
end
```

---

One way to get deal with the `create!` issue is to just get rid of any "blank" entries in a `before_filter`, e.g.:

```
before_filter :toss_blank_products

def toss_blank_products
  params[:products].reject! do |prod|
    # this logic may need to be more complex depending on the meaning of "blank"
    # for your model/form
    prod.values.all? &:blank
  end
end
```

Comment: Using `create!` makes sure all 5 Products are filled out and validated, what about if I only want to validate the ones which are filled out or half filled? Also, I get an error with `rescue` that is `syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue` so I had to change it back to what I have in my edit.

Comment: I just tried changing `create!` to `create` just to see if the user ID was assign but no luck still, hmmmmm......... Maybe my method is missing something?

Comment: @wrbg: Per the `rescue` exception I had omitted the `begin`. Per the `create!` issue I've edited my answer with a potential solution. Please see above.

Comment: OK I found the issue. It says `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_id`. If I make it available in the Product model, That's dangerous I believe. What should I do?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. When I put in my Product model for `attr_accessible` the `:user_id` it worked, but isn't this dangerous?

Comment: It could be. It occurs to me that the line immediately after `begin` could be changed to `@products = current_user.products.create!(`, which would (I think) eliminate the mass-assignment issue as well as the need to add `:user_id` to the `params[:product]` hash. I've updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, the user id is assigned with that code. Although I am curious about the `rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback`. It still doesn't redirect but just throws me an error: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`. Any idea?

Comment: Ah, perhaps that's the exception it should be rescuing instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
def create_multiple
  @products = params[:products].values.collect do |up|
    Product.new(up.merge(params[:product]).merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
  end

  # should run in a transaction, don't half save!
  Product.transaction do
    @valid = @products.all?(&:save)
  end

  if @valid
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Success!"
  else
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "An error occured, please try again."
  end
end
```

Comment: The merge isn't working for me: `merge(:user_id => current_user.id)`. Maybe it can't have two merges? I also had to change `@valid = @products.all?(&:save)` to `@products.each(&:save)` because I the users to have the ability to create 1 to 5 products and not need to create 5 that are valid.

Comment: "merge isn't working" is it an error ? or just does not merge ? it should work ? is current_user.nil? ? What is it that does not work? You can have any number of merges.

Comment: The Product doesn't even end up in the database. Let me dig deeper and see if I can find the issue.

Comment: I included my form just in case you have any other ideas.